# What is the difference between UTF8-in literal and unicode point?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I came a cross this [website](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1408&number=128&utf8=string-literal) which show the Unicode table.

when I print the letter 'ספר':

```
>>> x = 'ספר'
>>> x
'\xd7\xa1\xd7\xa4\xd7\xa8'
```

I get this characters `'\xd7\xa1\xd7\xa4\xd7\xa8'`.

I think that python encode the word 'ספר' with utf-8 Unicode, because it's the default, right?

but when I run this code:

```
>>> x = u'ספר'
>>> x
u'\u05e1\u05e4\u05e8'
```

I get this `u'\u05e1\u05e4\u05e8'`, which is a Unicode point, right?

How to convert from utf8-literal to Unicode point?

Comment: It's important to note that the byte string (the first `x` assignment above) and the Unicode point string (second `x` assignment) are equivalent with regard to the symbols in UTF-8: http://hexutf8.com?q=0xd70xa10xd70xa40xd70xa8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@In the first sample you created a *byte string* (type `str`). Your terminal determined the encoding (UTF-8 in this case).

In your second sample, you created a Unicode string (type `unicode`). Python auto-detected the encoding your terminal uses (from `sys.stdin.encoding`) and decoded the bytes from UTF-8 to Unicode code points.

You can make the same conversion from byte string to Unicode string by *decoding*:

```
unicode_x = bytestring_x.decode('utf8')
```

To go the other direction, you need to *encode*:

```
bytestring_x = unicode_x.encode('utf8')
```

You specified your literals by using the actual UTF-8 bytes for the characters; this works fine in a terminal but not in Python source code; Python 2 source code is loaded as ASCII text only. You can change this by setting a *source code encoding declaration*. This is specified in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/); it has to be the first or second line in your source file. For example:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

or you can stick to `\uhhhh` and `\xhh` escape sequences to represent non-ASCII characters.

You probably want to read up about the difference between Unicode and encoded (binary) byte strings, and how that relates to Python:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: what is the difference between unicode string and byte string ?

Comment: @david: different objects, one representing bytes (really integer values between 0 and 255 interpreted as ASCII text), the other Unicode codepoints.

Comment: @david: I've included some canonical links for you to study up on Unicode and encoded byte strings; Unicode is a closer representation of text than encoded bytes; just like you can use a `datetime.datetime()` to model a date and time quite closely, you can also represent that date-time combo in different ways in text (ISO 8601 is 2014-11-27T09:42:20+00:00, but you could also write Thursday the 27th of November 2014, at 18 minutes to 9 in the morning, ignoring the seconds and timezone); the `datetime.datetime()` object models the information more closely than the text version.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what do you mean with " you can stick to \uhhh and \xhh  "? you mean instead of using enocding UTF-8, I could write the utf-8 in literal and it will work fine ?

Comment: @david: you can see those in the value representations; `\uhhhh` lets you specify a Unicode code point in hex notation, `\xhh` lets you specify a byte in hex notation. The latter also works for specifying Unicode codepoints in the ASCII and Latin-1 ranges (because their values are <= 0xFF). Also see the [*String  Literals* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).